# javatlb or jactivex equivalent in Visual Studio 2005 or 2012

Tags: java, visual-studio, dll, activex, visual-studio-2005

Im trying to convert some DLLs to java classes, from google I found out that **javatlb** and **jactivex** command lines can do the job but they come with **Visual J++ 6.0** which I don't have and I think it is very old and hard to obtain, what I have is Visual Studio 2005 and now installing 2012, I would be glad if you know a way to convert my **tlb, dll** files to **java** classes or alternative up to date **javatlb** like commands! I can also use a **Java Type Library Wizard** alternative too. Thanks for reading!

Comment: There isn't. Visual J++ isn't even a .NET Language....Your question is sort of broad.

Comment: @Ramhound is there a way today to convert *.tlb or *.dll to Java Class?

Comment: A *tlb is the debugging information doesn't contain anything you need to convert the project.  The *.dll is compiled VJ++ and I am not aware of a method to decompile VJ++ code.  Why can't you just convert it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [com4j](https://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html) , did the job for me, very useful!